# Using Azure Resource Manager when microsoft AD graph is almost EOF

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm writing an application that needs to create service principals and grant them permissions to read/write to an Azure event hub.
Currently, I'm using the Java SDK (azure-resourcemanager) to create service principals and assign roles.
I have noticed that both az CLI and java SDK are calling the Azure AD Graph endpoints.
To my best understanding, the Azure AD Graph is reaching EOF soon. does this mean I need to replace my java code, or will the java code implementations be adjusted to the newer Microsoft graph API?
I have looked at the Microsoft Graph java sdk and it seems less mature and less intuitive to use than AzureResourceManager (which its API is much more similar to other Azure java SDKs)

Can anyone from the Azure team help with that?

Comment: Do you have any further concern? If my answer is helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to make the change currently.

If AAD Graph is retired, SDKs that rely on AAD Graph are bound to reintegrate with new APIs (most likely MS Graph) or Microsoft will release new SDKs(This is less likely, because the customer’s existing code will be changed significantly).

Besides, Microsoft Graph mainly manages AAD resources. See the samples here: [Create servicePrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-serviceprincipals?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#examples).

If you need to assign RBAC role you still need to look into other SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

As Allen mentioned, the likely scenario will be that certain future version of `azure-resourcemanager` would change to use MS graph internally for cases like creating a service principal, while keeping backward-combability on user-facing APIs (i.e., `.servicePincipals().define(NAME)...create()`).

The RBAC part will likely not impacted. Only the object ID of the service principal is required for RBAC, regardless of how that service principal is created/retrieved (via AAD graph or MS graph).

Currently it is not planned when this will happen.

Happened in 2.2.0 version.